# JIT the collate function in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, numba, pytorch-dataloader

I need to create a DataLoader where the collator function would require to have non trivial computation, actually a double layer loop which is significantly slowing down the training process. For example, consider this toy code where I try to use numba to JIT the collate function:

```
import torch
import torch.utils.data

import numba as nb


class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = np.zeros((100000, 300))
        self.B = np.ones((100000, 300))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.A[index], self.B[index]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.A.shape[0]

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def _collate_fn(batch):
    batch_data = np.zeros((len(batch), 300))
    for i in range(len(batch)):
        batch_data[i] = batch[i][0] + batch[i][1]

    return batch_data
```

and then I create the DataLoader as follows:

```
train_dataset = Dataset()

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=256,
    num_workers=6,
    collate_fn=_collate_fn,
    shuffle=True)
```

However this just gets stuck but works fine if I remove the JITing of the `_collate_fn`. I am not able to understand what is happening here. I don't have to stick to numba and can use anything which will help me overcome the loop inefficiencies in Python. TIA and Happy 12,021.